# Google Translate или Переводчик Гугл?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно написать название Google Translate по-русски: *Гугл / гугл(-)переводчик*?

Comment: Я за «переводчик Гугла». Чувствую, но обосновать не могу (ц)

Answer (score 1):

Сам "гугл" называет сервис как "Google Переводчик", это название и можно взять.

UPD:
Если нужно правильно написать именно по-русски, то "Гугл транслейт". Переводить отдельные слова не нужно, иначе вместо "Фольксваген" будем писать "Народный автомобиль".

Comment: В вопросе — как правильно написать... по-русски?

Answer (score 0):

Устоявшегося написания нет, но по логике должно быть **Гугл-переводчик**, так как первая часть слова не  склоняется. Если бы при склонении у слова *Гугл* появлялось окончание (вроде: *пользуюсь Гуглом переводчиком*), то напрашивалось бы раздельное написание.